# Sublime Text 3: do not close tabs automatically

Tags: sublimetext3

I am navigating the code of a big JavaScript library using Sublime Text 3. So I need to open a lot of tabs and switch between them to capture the code co-reference. However, Sublime closes 'unused' tabs automatically for me.

How to disable it? I googled but cannot find a solution. I find a shortcut `ctrl+shift+t` to restore the most recent closed file, but that is not enough. I need to disable the automatic closing, and that would  be better if someone shows me the short key to "display and select a file from all open files". Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you single-click on a file in the sidebar, Sublime displays it in a "temp" view that is overwritten the next time you single-click on a file. To open a file in a "permanent" tab that stays open even when other files are opened, you simply need to double-click on the file in the sidebar.

Answer (score 3):

A more direct solution that I find mildly preferable, at least until I can retrain myself to double-click when I want a tab to stay open:

In the Settings, set `preview_on_click` to `false`.

This is not quite what I want since it all it does is disable the behavior to open a preview tab on single click -- thereby forcing the user to always double click. But perhaps by working this way for a week or so I will be able to retrain my ingrained assumptions and can go back to the default behavior.

Comment: THANK YOU!! So much of a pain to double click every file to keep it open than to close ones I don't want! Especially when I'm not using the mouse/trackpad to open files with ⌘-p!

Answer (score 0):

Double click that file on left sidebar you do not want to close automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Worth saying another solution is to just save the file once its open and this will make it permanent as well. Tested in v4.